# Visual Studio not creating a "Properties" folder for a project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This is in VS2010 ...

I can't figure this out, but my assembly is not outputting a Properties folder with AssemblyInfo and the other bits that go along with it. I checked the csproj file and the following:

```
<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
```

Is present, yet on build nothing gets generated. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things in that folder are not generated during a build, they should exist and be included in the build. When you create a new solution/project, those files will be created. If you delete them, then you'd have to manually recreated them or copy them from a separate project (and update them).

The AppDesignerFolder just tells Visual Studio where it should look for some of the UI elements that can be used to update the files there (i.e. the version information in AssemblyInfo).