# Don't See Properties Folder in VS Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have two projects. One where I can see the properties folder within the project and the other I can't. I have right-clicked on the solution and selected properties, but I see no way to add the folder.

I have tried (within Windows), going to the folder of my project and adding the folder that way, but I still need a way to associate the project properties with that folder I have added.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900546/visual-studio-not-creating-a-properties-folder-for-a-project) thread. It says the folder is created by default when you create a project and if I delete them, I'll have to recreate it. I've never seen the folder on any of my projects, except one and I didn't delete it from the others, so not sure.

I attached a picture of what I am referring to in my project that actually has it if that would help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: are the projects generated from the same template? what template?

Comment: @elyashiv Yes. Same template that I created a long time ago. Do I need to make a new template? Or can I just add this folder in there since the project that shows it says all the necessary files and such.

Comment: Just as a thought... I think this is a difference between "old" projects and "new" ones... If I run into a project that gets opened and upgraded from an earlier VS (2008? 2005?), they don't seem to have the Properties folder. I just added a Folder, moved stuff inside and reloaded the project and it seems to act "normally" (Properties with wrench icon and References "folders" at top)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need not just add folder in windows explorer, but also include it in Project (with 'Show all files' option, find this folder under project and 'Include in project' from rigth click menu).

OR, just create it from within VS (right click on Project -> Add -> New folder, and name it 'Properties')

Comment: Thanks. I knew I needed to associate the project with it, but couldn't figure out how. That show all files button was kind of hidden. Thanks again.